# JSON API integration testing framework that is technology agnostic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, rspec

I am developing in a micro services architecture, currently each service is developed in ruby.

One of the advantages of decoupling services is a future ability to refactor a service from ruby to another technology, let's say Node.js

When I will do this refactor some time in future, I would want my integration tests to keep functioning.

Ideally, I would want to develop the integration tests in rspec (ruby), and to keep them functioning on a non-rails server via HTTP.

Is that possible with rspec? 
Which tool can provide this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is a behavior-driven development (BDD) framework for the **Ruby programming language**.  It is used for unit testing. It can;t be integrated with another tech stack

However, If it is all about doing the integration testing for your web services, I think [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) is something that will help you to achieve the same.

Cucumber as a tool is technology agnostic. However, you will have to design your integration tests in such a way that any helper libraries to execute or write the testcases could be easily replaced with the libraries of other language when you are changing you tech. stack for the webservices/test cases.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you test the endpoints exposed by the webservice and not how they are implemented , they should keep functioning.

You could achieve that by writing your integration tests in spock which is a beautiful BDD framework in groovy, using that you can hit the endpoints like

```
GET  /cars    ---> Check for the list of cars

POST /cars    ---> Add a car 

GET /cars/1   ---> Get a specific car details

PUT /cars/1   ---> Edit a specific car
```

Now when you are testing like this, it doesn't matter what the  implementation is  coz you are always testing the interface.